# error inserting caph-input in CAPH for angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tizen

i'm using CAPH-angular to develop an app for tizen Smart tv.

i'm adding the input tag as it said on the [tutorial](https://www.samsungdforum.com/caphdocs/main.html?type=angular#), but ir returns me an error, etc.

```
<caph-input class="input-user-login" input-type="text" on-focused="objFocus($event)" on-blurred="objBlur($event)" max-length="100" place-holder="Nombre de usuario" focusable="{depth: DEPTH.LOGIN, name: 'login-1', nextFocus: {right: 'login-2', down: 'login-2'}}" ></caph-input>
```

Console shows this:

> TypeError: a(...).assign is not a function

Aditionally can't get focus on the inputs.

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this error with 2 steps:

-Adding value

```
<caph-input class="input-user-login" input-type="text" on-focused="objFocus($event)" on-blurred="objBlur($event)" value="login_user"></caph-input>
```

-Adding the scope in controller

```
$scope.login_username = "";
```